# How to authenticate a SharePoint 2013 REST API request from an HTML Application?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest

I am creating an HTML application that needs to access data from SharePoint 2013 List using REST APIs. 
eg - `sharePointsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items`.  
The HTML application is on a different server and is using JavaScript to access data. **How do i authenticate before calling the REST APIin JavaScript**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ADAL library to Authenticate with AZURE

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151135.aspx
- https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js
- http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/10/28/adal-javascript-and-angularjs-deep-dive/

Comment: Not sure how authenticating to Azure helps in accessing another onprem server?

Comment: Hi Danny, Thanks but as Robert said, both my applications are onprem.  Html application is on non sharepoint server.